# Graph composed of matchings and K_4

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G′ = (V, E_1 \cup E_2 \cup E_3)$ be a graph, where $E_1$ and $E_2$ are (nonempty) matchings
and $E_3$ is the set of edges of a nonempty collection of pairwise vertex disjoint copies of $K_4$.
Prove that the chromatic number of $G′$ is $4$.

Comment: What does this mean? Are the vertices just vertices of the $K_4$s?

Comment: @IgorRivin It doesn't matter, does it? A vertex which is not in a $K_4$ has degree at most $2$, so we may as well assume that every vertex is in a $K_4$.

Comment: Yes @IgorRivin I have made that assumption too

Comment: @Joshua: did you find the answer? I toyed with the problem for a while, but couldn't figure it out. I can do it for K4's + 1 matching (i.e. E2 = empty).